# org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Don't change the reference to a collection with delete-orphan enabled

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

i'm using spring data jpa.
when i want to clone an entity with one to many relation,

```
    fun clonePurchaseOrder(purchaseOrder: PurchaseOrder, operator: String): PurchaseOrder {
        //prepare data
        val items = purchaseOrder.items
        //detach
        items.forEach { entityManager.detach(it) }
        purchaseOrder.costRevise?.let { entityManager.detach(it) }
        entityManager.detach(purchaseOrder)
        purchaseOrder.id = null
        //modify
        items.forEach {
            it.id = null
            it.purchaseOrder = purchaseOrder
        }     
        //modify purchaseOrder
        val now = Date()
        return purchaseOrder.apply {
            number = null
            costRevise = null
            paymentHistories = mutableListOf()
            status = PurchaseOrder.Status.DRAFT
            createTime = now
            creator = operator
            modifyTime = now
            submitTime = null
            submitOperator = null
            closeOperator = null
            closeReason = null
            closeTime = null
        }.save()
    }
```

i set the purchaseOrder id =null, and each items id = null, but get the follw exception

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Don't change the reference to a collection with delete-orphan enabled : com.hkmci.web.bms2.backend.database.entity.PurchaseOrder.items; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Don't change the reference to a collection with delete-orphan enabled : com.hkmci.web.bms2.backend.database.entity.PurchaseOrder.items
```

here is purchaseOrder entity and items entity

```
@Entity
class PurchaseOrder(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long? = null,

    ...(other Column)

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "purchaseOrder", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
    var items: MutableList<PurchaseOrderItem> = mutableListOf(),

    ...(other Column)
```

```
@Entity
class PurchaseOrderItem(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long? = null,

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    var purchaseOrder: PurchaseOrder,

    ...(other column)
```

can any one help with this?

Comment: You are not cloning the items. You should create new instances of each object and set the fields to the values of the originals (except ID)

Comment: but my items detached one by one first, then set the id = null, and set the purchaseOrder point to the new one without id. i also see the console print insert query for both purchaseOrder and items.

Comment: In my project, there is other place used this method and cloned successfully. The code logic seems same but only have one difference: the parent entity primary key are String and generated from start, not set null. is this the root case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//clone a purchaseOrder, new purchaseOrder will be reset to Draft
    fun clonePurchaseOrder(purchaseOrder: PurchaseOrder, operator: String): PurchaseOrder {
        //clear all relationships
        purchaseOrder.costRevise?.let { entityManager.detach(it) }
        purchaseOrder.items.forEach {
            entityManager.detach(it)
            it.id = null
        }
        purchaseOrder.paymentHistories.forEach {
            entityManager.detach(it)
        }
        entityManager.detach(purchaseOrder)
        //reset all fields
        val now = Date()
        purchaseOrder.apply {
            id = null
            number = null
            costRevise = null
            items = items.toMutableList()
            paymentHistories = mutableListOf()
            status = PurchaseOrder.Status.DRAFT
            createTime = now
            creator = operator
            modifyTime = now
            submitTime = null
            submitOperator = null
            closeOperator = null
            closeReason = null
            closeTime = null
        }
        //save
        return purchaseOrderRepository.save(purchaseOrder)
    }
```

No need to reassociate items and purchaseOrder , just clear all relationships, set id = null and save